# how to flag % revenue from a cumulative total

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table customer as like below

[image]

The total revenue generated by all 10 customers is 100,000. Out of this total revenue customer A, B, C has contributed almost 85% of revenue. I want to divide my customers based on 80-20 rule, I want to flag A,B,C as 80% revenue customers and remaining as 20% revenue customers

How we can achieve this in SQL

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select customer, amount,  
  if(flag, '80%', if(row_number() over(partition by flag order by amount desc) = 1, '80%', '20%')) || ' revenue' as flag
from (
  select *, 
    (sum(amount) over(order by amount desc, customer)) / (sum(amount) over()) < 0.8 flag
  from your_table
)
```

slightly refactored version is

```
select customer, amount,  
  if(flag and row_number() over(partition by flag order by amount desc) > 1, '20%', '80%') || ' revenue' as flag
from (
  select *, 
    amount < percentile_cont(amount, 0.8) over() flag
  from your_table
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]